# Adding time enabled feature to layer running newest to oldest

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, time

I am seeking information about the Time Enabled feature of my map created in ArcGIS 10.1, Basic (ArcView).

Specifically, I am wondering if the layer can be made to run from newest to oldest.  I update my layer a few times a year adding new information but I need the layer to open at the newest data and progress to the oldest data.  I have data spanning from 2007-2014, so I need the 2014 data to be displayed first then to progress backwards to 2007.  My published map is NC Shellfish Lease Siting Tool (UNCW).

Comment: To my knowledge this isn't possible. There's a playback setting than can loop between forward and reverse (so the display ping-pongs), and ArcGIS Pro appears to have a reverse mode, but for the normal Time Slider, it appears you can't. I did see an [ArcGIS Idea](https://esri.secure.force.com/ideaView?id=087300000008HpS&returnUrl=%2Fapex%2FideaList%3Fc%3D09a300000004xET%26p%3D351%26sort%3Drecent) for it.

Comment: Yes, "Time slider plays backward" is exactly what I need too.  Please 'promote' the idea so it gets more points and get better noticed. ESRI Support mentioned ArcGIS Pro but they also said it is not compatible with ArcGIS Online which is where my map is published. Thanks though.